# Java String.split() function gives wrong outputs

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I have a string of `"A   B   C"` and I have this line of code to split it:

```
String[] reFormatted = TestString.split("   ");
System.out.println(reFormatted.toString());
```

and the output I get is this:

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@30f1c0
```

if I put this string array in a foreach loop like this:

```
for(String s : reFormatted){
   System.out.println(reFormatted);
}
```

I get the output of:

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@30f1c0
[Ljava.lang.String;@30f1c0
[Ljava.lang.String;@30f1c0
```

what is the problem here? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `for(String s : reFormatted){
   System.out.println(s);
}`

Comment: reFormatted is an array type, you can check it by printing this `reFormatted.getClass().getName()` to check the type of the variable. And you cannot print the array, it will return you the address of where the array is stored in the memory. Instead, you need to print the elements of the array, as others pointed out, print the variable `s` in the for loop. Good Luck!

Comment: To print an array you can write ```System.out.println(Arrays.asList(reFormatted))```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are printing the address of the variable `reFormatted` and for the for loop, you should print `s` not `reFormatted`

```java
for(String s : reFormatted){
    // System.out.println(reFormatted);
    System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: address? it is more like the hash code (can be the address, despite not sure what the address is for java, virtual memory and so) and the class name

Comment: Ooh! true I missed that, let me re-try!